# Opimizing Code. How to get 2 variables in loop

Tags: javascript, loops, variables, for-loop, optimization

I'm trying to optimize this code.

```
document.getElementById("b3").innerHTML = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c2").innerHTML) * parseFloat(document.getElementById("b1").value);
            document.getElementById("c3").innerHTML = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b3").innerHTML) + parseFloat(document.getElementById("a3").value);
            document.getElementById("b4").innerHTML = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c3").innerHTML) * parseFloat(document.getElementById("b1").value);
            document.getElementById("c4").innerHTML = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b4").innerHTML) + parseFloat(document.getElementById("a4").value);
            document.getElementById("b5").innerHTML = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c4").innerHTML) * parseFloat(document.getElementById("b1").value);
            document.getElementById("c5").innerHTML = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b5").innerHTML) + parseFloat(document.getElementById("a5").value);
            document.getElementById("b6").innerHTML = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c5").innerHTML) * parseFloat(document.getElementById("b1").value);
            document.getElementById("c6").innerHTML = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b6").innerHTML) + parseFloat(document.getElementById("a6").value);
            document.getElementById("b7").innerHTML = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c6").innerHTML) * parseFloat(document.getElementById("b1").value);
            document.getElementById("c7").innerHTML = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b7").innerHTML) + parseFloat(document.getElementById("a7").value);
            document.getElementById("b8").innerHTML = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c7").innerHTML) * parseFloat(document.getElementById("b1").value);
            document.getElementById("c8").innerHTML = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b8").innerHTML) + parseFloat(document.getElementById("a8").value);
            document.getElementById("b9").innerHTML = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c8").innerHTML) * parseFloat(document.getElementById("b1").value);
            document.getElementById("c9").innerHTML = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b9").innerHTML) + parseFloat(document.getElementById("a9").value);
            document.getElementById("b10").innerHTML = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c9").innerHTML) * parseFloat(document.getElementById("b1").value);
```

I've tried like this, but two variables have crashed script.

```
for (var i = 2; i < 11; i++; var x = 3; x < 12; x++)
{
   document.getElementById("b" + x).innerHTML = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c" + i).innerHTML) * parseFloat(document.getElementById("b1").value);
   document.getElementById("c" + x).innerHTML = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b" + x).innerHTML) + parseFloat(document.getElementById("a" + x).value);
}
```

Comment: This isn't a great question, but it doesn't seem so bad that it should be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can declare and increment more than one variable.. but you must use ,

```
for (var i = 2,x = 3; i < 11; i++,x++)
{
   document.getElementById("b" + x).innerHTML = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c" + i).innerHTML) * parseFloat(document.getElementById("b1").value);
   document.getElementById("c" + x).innerHTML = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b" + x).innerHTML) + parseFloat(document.getElementById("a" + x).value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `i` as the loop counter, and set `x` equal to `i+1`.

```
var i, x;
for(i = 2; i < 11; i++) {
    x = i+1;
    document.getElementById("b" + x).innerHTML = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c" + i).innerHTML) * parseFloat(document.getElementById("b1").value);
    document.getElementById("c" + x).innerHTML = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b" + x).innerHTML) + parseFloat(document.getElementById("a" + x).value);
}
```